# Add a new custom actions group to Site Settings in O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-settings, custom-action

I need to add a new `Custom Actions Group` to `Site Settings` page and inside this group a new `custom link`.

On the click of this `custom link` the user should be redirected to the Provider Hosted App that I have created.

Is this achievable in O365? If Yes, then how can this be implemented?

Please refer the screen shot below to understand where I want to add the new group and link. I hope that will make my question clear.

[image]

Comment: Is your question regarding how to add a Custom Group to site collection via a provider hosted app. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this code for adding custom action to the site settings page.

```
// Add site settings link
UserCustomAction siteSettingLink = clientContext.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
siteSettingLink.Group = "SiteTasks";
siteSettingLink.Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings";
siteSettingLink.Name = "Sample_CustomSiteSetting";
siteSettingLink.Sequence = 1000;
siteSettingLink.Url = string.Format(DeployManager.appUrl, clientContext.Url);
siteSettingLink.Title = "Modify Site Metadata";
siteSettingLink.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

And to add site actions link

```
//Add site actions link
UserCustomAction siteAction = clientContext.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
siteAction.Group = "SiteActions";
siteAction.Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu";
siteAction.Name = "Sample_CustomAction";
siteAction.Sequence = 1000;
siteAction.Url = string.Format(DeployManager.appUrl, clientContext.Url); ;
siteAction.Title = "Modify Site Metadata";
siteAction.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Now I get what you asked, obviously I answered based on the previous question. please use proper terms for getting answers easily.

Comment: Can you please share the reference link for this? It would be useful.

Comment: https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/add-site-setting-and-site-action-from-csom/

Comment: Thanks for this. it works great. Can you please help on how can I create new Custom Action Group to add the link?