# full control site setting

Tags: 2013, csom, custom-actions

In site setting I want to hide a link in the Site Actions group from the Full Control users.

[image]

Anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As `Modify Site Metadata` seems like it's a custom action, you need to return to the code used to add it. CSOM accepts `Rights` attribute, which are based on [SPBasePermission enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx). You need to define a higher-than-site-owner-level permission right, which would be `ManageWeb`.

So, add the following to your code:

```
Rights = "ManageWeb"
```

The complete code would be something like:

```
UserCustomAction siteAction = clientContext.Web.UserCustomActions.Add();
siteAction.Group = "SiteActions";
siteAction.Location = "Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu";
siteAction.Name = "Sample_CustomAction";
siteAction.Sequence = 1000;
siteAction.Url = string.Format(DeployManager.appUrl, clientContext.Url); ;
siteAction.Title = "Modify Site Metadata";
siteAction.Rights = "ManageWeb"; 
siteAction.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

References [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715590/how-to-add-custom-action-in-sharepoint-that-visible-only-for-specific-group) & [2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184766/add-a-new-custom-actions-group-to-site-settings-in-o365).

Comment: May I ask why -1?